# C char* pointers pointing to same location where they definitely shouldn't

Tags: c, linux, pointers, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to write a simple C program on Ubuntu using Eclipse CDT (yes, I'm more comfortable with an IDE and I'm used to Eclipse from Java development), and I'm stuck with something weird. On one part of my code, I initialize a char array in a function, and it is by default pointing to the same location with one of the inputs, which has nothing to do with that char array. Here is my code:

```
char* subdir(const char input[], const char dir[]){
[*] int totallen = strlen(input) + strlen(dir) + 2;
    char retval[totallen];
    strcpy(retval, input);
    strcat(retval, dir);
...}
```

Ok at the part I've marked with [*], there is a checkpoint. Even at that breakpoint, when I check y locals, I see that retval is pointing to the same address with my argument input. It not even possible as input comes from another function and retval is created in this function. Is is me being unexperienced with C and missing something, or is there a bug somewhere with the C compiler?

It seems so obvious to me that they should't point to the same (and a valid, of course, they aren't NULL) location. When the code goes on, it literally messes up everything; I get random characters and shapes in console and the program crashes.

Comment: We'd have to see the calling code to make sense out of it. It would also help to see the rest of this function to see what it returns. (For example, if it tried to return `retval` and then pass that to another instance of the function, that would cause exactly this problem. The `retval` array goes out of scope when the function returns. A pointer to its former address will point to garbage.)

Comment: retval is not initialized yet, what if you step 2 more lines?

Comment: Thinking a bit further: are you returning `retval` from the function? You must not do that, because it only exists on the stack, you are triggering undefined behavior that way. Also not that line 2 of your code is only valid starting with C99

Comment: note that retval does not exist at your checkpoint

Comment: At that line the storage for `retval` hasn't been allocated, so I don't think you can expect the debugger to display anything sensible.

Comment: @all: retval isn't initialized but i think it's preallocated due to optimization issues (that's the only logical explanation i have for that), and after stepping, it doesn't even step on that line, it skips the line and stops on strcpy, and at strcpy it still points to the same address.

Comment: I've added an example in my answer, I think it is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Classic SO voting. The answers that explain the actual problem, UB from returning a stack pointer, all get downvoted. The answers that don't mention this do not. What gives?!!

Comment: i didn't downvote any answers. and i've just realized that i didn't vote yours before, and voted it up as it deserved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to check the address of `retval` BEFORE it appears, it being a VLA and all (by definition the compiler and the debugger don't know much about it, it's generated at runtime on the stack).

Try checking its address *after* its point of definition.

#### EDIT

I just read the "*I get random characters and shapes in console*". It's obvious now that you are returning the VLA and expecting things to work.

**A VLA is only valid inside the block where it was defined**. Using it outside is undefined behavior and thus very dangerous. Even if the size were constant, it *still* wouldn't be valid to return it from the function. In this case you most definitely want to `malloc` the memory.

Comment: it is the same after definition. the stepper skips the line and stops directly at strcpy.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu I think I'll try this myself :-?

Comment: after reading the other answers, i think it has something to do with the non constant size memory allocation. i'll try malloc.

Comment: @can The problem is returning a pointer to stack allocated memory. Mine and Joe's answers describe the real issue.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu I did mention it's a VLA, didn't I ? :-) I tried your code and couldn't reproduce the thing. GDB reports different addresses even *before* the point of definition.

Comment: weird that it just reports the same address. anyway, i'll be revising the code and changing VLA initializations with mallocs, and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta keep working on these answers to stay ahead!!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ahead of what ? :-) I was genuinely intrigued about the issue and now I wanted to improve my answer because I have 3 not-so-deserved upvotes on it. Had nobody voted I would have simply deleted like I usually do.

Comment: @cnicutar heh I'm just teasing. The truth is I never noticed the lack of return statement. I just saw `retval` VLA, `char*` return type, and jumped to conclusions!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, coupled with the mention of "weird characters" it's obvious you were right :-)

Comment: the problem was returning local variable pointer, and i changed it to allocate memory using malloc, and the problem is gone. i think it now solves the "mysterious and randomly reproducing weird symbols". thank you all for helping a c newbie :)

Comment: Make sure that you free() the string that you return or it will create a memory leak!!

Answer (score 2):

What cnicutar said.

I hate people who do this, so I hate me ... but ... Arrays of non-const size are a C99 extension and not supported by C++.  Of course GCC has extensions to make it happen.

Under the covers you are essentially doing an _alloca, so your odds of blowing out the stack are proportional to who has access to abuse the function.

Finally, I hope it doesn't actually get returned, because that would be returning a pointer to a stack allocated array, which would be your real problem since that array is gone as of the point of return.

In C++ you would typically use a string class.

In C you would either pass a pointer and length in as parameters, or a pointer to a pointer (or return a pointer) and specify the calls should call free() on it when done.  These solutions all suck because they are error prone to leaks or truncation or overflow. :/

Answer (score 2):

Well, your fundamental problem is that you are returning a pointer to the stack allocated VLA. You can't do that. Pointers to local variables are only valid inside the scope of the function that declares them. Your code results in  Undefined Behaviour.

At least I am assuming that somewhere in the `.....` in the real code is the line `return retval`.

You'll need to use heap allocation, or pass a suitably sized buffer to the function.

As well as that, you only need +1 rather than +2 in the length calculation - there is only one null-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `retval` to a character pointer and allocating your buffer using `malloc()`.

Comment: And don't forget to free the memory when it is no longer used …

Answer (score 1):

Pass the two string arguments as, char * or const char *

Rather than returning char *, you should just pass another parameter with a string pointer that you already malloc'd space for.

Return bool or int describing what happened in the function, and use the parameter you passed to store the result.

Lastly don't forget to free the memory since you're having to malloc space for the string on the heap...

```
//retstr is not a const like the other two
bool subdir(const char *input, const char *dir,char *retstr){
    strcpy(retstr, input);
    strcat(retstr, dir);
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    char h[]="Hello ";
    char w[]="World!";
    char *greet=(char*)malloc(strlen(h)+strlen(w)+1); //Size of the result plus room for the terminator!
    subdir(h,w,greet);
    printf("%s",greet);
    return 1;
}
```

This will print: "Hello World!" added together by your function.

Also when you're creating a string on the fly you must malloc. The compiler doesn't know how long the two other strings are going to be, thus using char greet[totallen]; shouldn't work.

Comment: This is a good answer, in my view, but you fail to address what is wrong with  the code in the question. Without covering that topic, the person asking the question is just faced with what appears to be magic. Change the code to this and, hey presto! it works.

Comment: this clarifies even more with cnicutar's explanation. thanks for the example. i wish i could choose two accepted answers :)

Comment: I left a comment on cnicutar's answer about not forgetting free() so you don't leave the string in the memory forever, if you were calling this function many times that would be bad thing to forget.  It's a really easy mistake to make, and sometimes a very hard one to catch.

Comment: thanks. yes, I'm trying to avoid memory leaks as much as possible.